# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException en JComboBox

Tags: java, javafx

He estado intentando de llenar un JComboBox, y me arrojado el sgte error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Damas.Game.llenarJCombo(Game.java:147)
at Damas.Game.<init>(Game.java:39)
at Damas.Damas.<init>(Damas.java:29)
at registros.PanelPresentacion.BDamasActionPerformed(PanelPresentacion.java:89)
at registros.PanelPresentacion$1.actionPerformed(PanelPresentacion.java:41)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6632)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6397)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5008)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2762)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

y el error solamente se crea cuando trato de usar los JComboBox creados desde el JFrame.
he intentado desde el addItem que deberia agregar el String al JComboBox, hasta lo ultimo que hice es esto que encontre en la pagina numero 2 de google, que es usar el setModel:

```
 private void llenarJCombo() {

    int tam = jugadoras.size();

    String[] armadora = new String[tam];
    String[] central = new String[tam];
    String[] punta = new String[tam];
    String[] opuesto = new String[tam];
    String[] liberos = new String[tam];

    for (int i = 0; i < jugadoras.size(); i++) {
        String aux = jugadoras.get(i).getPosicion().toLowerCase();
        switch (aux) {
            case "punta":
                punta[i] = jugadoras.get(i).getNombre();
                break;
            case "central":
                central[i] = jugadoras.get(i).getNombre();
                break;
            case "armadora":
                armadora[i] = jugadoras.get(i).getNombre();
                break;
            case "opuesto":
                opuesto[i] = jugadoras.get(i).getNombre();
                break;
            case "libero":
                liberos[i] = jugadoras.get(i).getNombre();
                break;
        }
    }

    JCArmadoras.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(armadora));
    JCPtasDefen.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(punta));
    JCCentralDefen.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(central));
    JCOpuesto.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(opuesto));
    JCPtasOfen.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(punta));
    JCCentralOfen.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(central));
    JCLibero.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(liberos));

}
```

p.d.: jugadoras es un Arraylist de la clase Jugadora, que contiene:
-int numero
-String nombre
-int edad
-String posicion
-int rendimiento
-int[] referencias (la idea de este arreglo es sacar un porcentaje de efectividad en saque,recepción,armada,ataque y bloqueo, el cual varia en la inciacion de ello por si es el jugador de cancha o es el defensor(libero))

Comment: Según el stack trace, la excepción ocurre en la clase Game, línea 147. Cuál es la línea 147 en tu clase Game?

Comment: aparece el llamado al primer JComboBox, que en este caso es JCArmadoras

Comment: Lo que no termino de entender de tu código es que estás usando el método setModel como estático? Porque según el javadoc no es estático https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setModel(javax.swing.ComboBoxModel)

Ahora bien, si como sospecho en realidad JCArmadoras, etc. son instancias de JComboBox, primero, están mal nombradas con mayúsculas porque entonces no parecen ser instancias sino el nombre de la clase, y eso causa confusión, y segundo, el problema es que no instanciaste los JComboBox correctamente (o no sé, porque no muestras de dónde vienen).